# Visual Studio For Mac Designer Error

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin-studio

I have downloaded VS For Mac Preview and created a new Xamarin Forms IOS/Android Solution using the portable library. When i try and load the XAML designer though to view the startup page I get the error "Invalid XAML : default constructor not found for Xamarin.Forms.Applicaton". I have not made any changes to the project code generated by VS For Mac and the only thing I did was to build the Android project as this is required before the designer can be opened. I also had to download the latest versions of the Android SDK via the SDK Manager.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there are two preview modes, one for iOS and one for Android - if you can't see both tabs, drag the frame over a bit. I can't currently get the Android preview to work right even though it builds, but for iOS to work it looks like you simply need to update the Xamarin.Forms package. Go to the 'Project' menu and select 'Update NuGet Packages.' Then, restart Visual Studio for Mac and it should be working. It is very slow to load, however. I had to rebuild my project *and* select 'Update NuGet Packages' a second time before it actually showed up.

I'm still trying to figure out why Android preview does not work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks you for the help , I can now see the designer with the basic Welcome To Xamarin Forms startup page. Next question is that in my Toolbox I do not see any controls. I wold have expected to see the common Xamarin controls here which can then be dropped onto the controller. Any idea why the toolbox is empty ? Again thank you for your help.

Comment: I actually tried to updating the NuGet packages and after restarting the VS for mac and rebuilding the whole solution the android preview worked. Yeah but the toolbox issue still remains.

Comment: I think I figured out why there is no toolbox. Since there is no designer for the xamarin forms the only way to design the UI is by writing XML code.

Comment: Wow , much as I love the  idea of VS for Mac and Xamarin I am not sure writing the XML by hand is really what people are looking for. The great thing about VS is how easy it is to design and add code to the UI. Hopefully this is just an issue with the Preview version and not how it will be on release.

Comment: I believe it will be addressed at some point, but maybe not on the first release. There is, as far as I can see, no technical reason why they'd not be able to implement a designer not unlike the one used for Windows XAML projects. It'd be ideal if they could reuse that, and I think maybe that is in the cards.